# File operations with Junit

Tags: java, junit

In my program, I am creating files whenever I `create/update/remove` my objects to send information to an existing FTP server. For this purpose, I created a folder let say `INFO_FOLDER` and I am able to create and send these files to server.

On the other hand, while running unit tests, file are created into same folder. This is not nice since there might be real program related files in there and I do not want to mix it up with test related files.

Either I need to delete each file created in each test via `@After` method, or I need to use different folder for unit test purpose. I do not know if the second one is possible.

How could I handle this problem? Which way is more elegant? Or is there any other well known solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are unit testing your code you shouldn't deal with I/O since **the File System is an external resource** and you should use Test Doubles (Mocks). Unit Testing is all about testing a single thing in isolation.

If your method just outputs to the FS then you could verify that the specific `write` method was called with [Mockito.verify](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify). It should be better to write integration tests to check if the components integrate together properly (i.e your code, with the FS). For example,

Production code:

```
  public void writeToOutput(String path) {
    FS.writeOutput(path);
  }
```

Testing code:

```
@Test
  public void writes_to_output() {
    String path = "./sample.txt";
    FS fs = mock(FS.class);           //mock the class that writes to output

    service.writeToOutput(path);      //do the action

    verify(fs).writeOutput(path);     //verify that your FS class called writeToOutput with the given argument
  }
```

However, if you want to do an integration test and check that the file was written in the FS then you should redirect the output to a different location (if you have your path hard coded on the production code then its impossible to redirect it somewhere else), inside your test directory.

**You should never run tests that mess up your production code (the src folder)**.